# general solution to a linear recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

So a problem is asking me to find a general solution to a linear recursion

given by $A_{n+2} = 9 A_{n+1}-20A_n$.

initial conditions are $A_0=3$ and $A_1=6$.

What would be value of $A_8$?

so the procedure is to find first the characteristic polynomial $r^2- 9r+ 20 = 0$. I got that $A_8 = 256$.
Im wondering if that is the correct  answer

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

Solving the recursion, you get $$A_n = -6 \times 5^n + 9 \times 4^n$$

Therefore $$A_8= -1753926$$

Comment: thank you  , your answer prompted me  check my  procedure and i found a really silly error